# Is possible in vim to delete a line after a word or character?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have this file

```
name ...
line1

name ...
line 2

name ...
line 3

etc
```

I want to delete lines after the "..." sequence
,and preserve the others: is possible?

The result will be

```
name ...


name ...


name ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this with `:g/regexp/+d`

In your case this would (probably) be `:g/\.\.\./+d`

This (internally) marks all lines matching the regexp and then deletes the next line